# Contextily adds blank space to the right of matplotlib panel plot

Tags: python, geopandas, matplotlib

I am unsure why I get this blank space to the right hand side of my panel plot when I add a contextily basemap.

See the image example below:

[image]

Here is a reproducible example:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import contextily as cx  

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(8,8))
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=.2, wspace=.2)
fig.set_facecolor('lightgrey')

geom = [{
    'type':'Feature',
    'geometry': {
        'type': 'Polygon',
        'coordinates': [[
            [2.0,7.0],[2.0,8.0],[3.0,8.0],[3.0,7.0]
        ]],
    },
    'properties': {}
}]

geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(geom)

geo_df.plot(facecolor="none", edgecolor="grey", ax=ax1[0])
geo_df.plot(facecolor="none", edgecolor="grey", ax=ax1[1])
geo_df.plot(facecolor="none", edgecolor="grey", ax=ax2[0])
geo_df.plot(facecolor="none", edgecolor="grey", ax=ax2[1])

# crs = 'epsg:4326'
# cx.add_basemap(ax1[0], crs=crs)
# cx.add_basemap(ax1[1], crs=crs)
# cx.add_basemap(ax2[0], crs=crs)
# cx.add_basemap(ax2[1], crs=crs)

plt.savefig('my_figure.png',
pad_inches=0.4,
bbox_inches='tight'
)
plt.close()
```

If I run this code without the contextily background, the panel plot looks perfect.

Why would this be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is contextily background writing. Change `figsize=(8,8)` to `figsize=(16,16)` and your problem will be solved.